# Collect sorted map | Spring WebFlux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive

I have a Flux which I'm converting to map using flux.collectMultiMap().

The key is of String type. How can I ensure that the resulting map is always sorted? In see we have collectSortedList, sort methods in Flux but those will only sort a list or Flux and not map.

Comment: Do you want a Map whose values are sorted lists, or a map whose keys are sorted ? Because there's two responses to your question, each answering one of both scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `collectMultiMap` overloaded version with a `Supplier` as 3rd argument. That means you also need to provide a value mapper. In case you don't specify one already, use `Function.identity()`. For instance:

```
Mono<Map<String, Collection<YourType>>> mono = flux.collectMultiMap(
        t -> extractStringFromT(t),
        Function.identity(),
        TreeMap::new
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample example shown below

```
public class FluxMapSortingExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flux<Tuple2<String, Integer>> flux = Flux.just(
                Tuple2.of("one", 1),
                Tuple2.of("three", 3),
                Tuple2.of("two", 2)
        );

        Mono<Map<String, Integer>> sortedMapMono = flux.collectSortedList((t1, t2) -> t1.getT1().compareTo(t2.getT1()))
                .map(sortedList ->
                        sortedList.stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Tuple2::getT1, Tuple2::getT2))
                );

        sortedMapMono.subscribe(sortedMap -> {
            System.out.println("Sorted Map: " + sortedMap);
        });
    }
}
```